# How to set test name for junit test - but not using name of test method?

Tags: java, junit

I have complex junit test. I want to set name/description of this test which will be showed only if test fail, otherwise I need only simple name.

I can do this in common way and use name of test method as description of that this method do.

```
@Test
/**
 * Should return something when some parameter is set to specific value 
 * and other parameter is set to another specific value and everything is
 * executed in specific context under specific environment
 */
public void test42() {
    ....
}

@Test()
//not like that
public void shouldReturnSomethingWhenSomeParameterIsSetToSpecificValueAndOtherParameterIs SetToAnotherSpecificValueAandEverythingIsExecutedInSpecificContextUnderSpecificEnvironment() {
    ....
}
```

Expectation is that description from command will be exposed when test fail.
Something like that:

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   FooTest.test42:110 
[ERROR]   > Should return something when some parameter is set to specific value 
[ERROR]   > and other parameter is set to another specific value and everything is
[ERROR]   > executed in specific context under specific environment
Expecting:
  <[8, 3]>
to contain only:
  <[9, 2]>
elements not found:
  <[9, 2]>
and elements not expected:
  <[8, 3]>

[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 85, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Names should be consistent so that you can track reliability of the test over time - are you supplying an error message when you call `assert`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Why wouldn't using a simple name and a detailed assertion method be enough?

Answer (score 1):

`@Test` interface doesn't have any such values. But it's the assertion errors, that fail the test, so you can add a message to the specific assertions, for example:

```
assertTrue("Those are not equal", 0 == 1);
```

or, for example, using hamcrest you can pass a reason:

```
assertThat("Those should be equal", 0, is(equalTo(0)));
```

The messages will be printed on failure.

Comment: this is message which describe type of error - not type of test.

Comment: Correct, test is more general, this message will give you more information. If you want, you can add some description for every test and pass it to every assertion, but that would be a bit verbose.